# "Could not open Source file: Could not find a part of the path" - Error getting while running msbuild command

Tags: msbuild

while running the msbuild command specifically the below one:-

```
msbuild /p:Configuration=Release;DeployOnBuild=True;DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish;WebPublishMethod=FileSystem;PublishProvider=FileSystem;LastUsedBuildConfiguration=Release;ExcludeApp_Data=False;publishUrl=../CommercePackageContent/wwwroot;DeleteExistingFiles=True
```

On the specific solution (having .csproj file), getting the below error:-

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.
Publishing.targets(2309,5): error : Could not open Source file: Could not find a part of the path 'obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Apps\Web.config'
```

Can you please tell me any specific reason behind this error message and how do I get resolve it?

FYI
Web.config content looks like :-

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration>
  <!--
  <system. Web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system. Web>
  -->
  <appSettings>
    <add key="epi:HelpUrl" value="http://webhelp.episerver.com/latest/en/EpiserverUserGuide_csh.htm" />
  </appSettings>
  <system. Web>
    <pages validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false"></pages>
  </system. Web>
</configuration>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What debugging and troubleshooting steps have you already tried?

Comment: I tried to follow this blog - https://blog.aabech.no/archive/web-deploy-says-could-not-open-source-file-some-webconfig-when-you-publish-an-umbraco-site/
but still that didn't help

Comment: Your msbuild command doesn't specify the file to use. Is msbuild finding and reporting that it is using your .sln file? How many projects are in the solution? Are all the projects web projects? Is the project that is failing a library project and not a web project? Does the project that is failing have a web.config file?

Answer (score 0):

After checking many sites found out that it can be solved by adding

```
AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False
```

in msbuild command then it resolves my issues, which I tried earlier on web.config file itself. So the whole code to use will be

```
msbuild /p:Configuration=Release;DeployOnBuild=True;DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish;WebPublishMethod=FileSystem;PublishProvider=FileSystem;LastUsedBuildConfiguration=Release;ExcludeApp_Data=False;PublishUrl=../CommercePackageContent/wwwroot;DeleteExistingFiles=False;AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False
```